# Почему не видит второй параметр RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Проблема!

Нужно, чтобы разбивалось на страницы, а почему-то не видит 2-й параметр PAGE.

Что делать?

```
RewriteRule ^genre/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? /php/genres.php?genresurl=$1
RewriteRule ^genre/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/page-([^/]*)$ /php/genres.php?genresurl=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второе правило никогда не сработает, потому что первое будет срабатывать раньше. Можно просто поменять их местами, а можно в конец первого правила добавить `$`.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!